# Connecting to Cross Domain Dynamics CRM Web API (Unauthorized)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-webapi

I'm having a problem connecting to the Dynamics CRM Web API.

I'm trying to connect to the Web API from an external .NET Core page, using javascript but I keep getting the `401 Unauthorized error`. It seems a cross domain problem. The error is:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Basically I'm at the domain `domain1.com`, and I need to run a web api call at `domain2.com` using javascript.

So how can I achieve that? I do not want my user to be prompted to authenticate, but I need to manage that by the code.

Also, I'm not using Azure to authenticate but I'm using ADFS.

This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "json",
    url: "https://crm.anuv.com.br/api/data/v8.2/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='account')",
    beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\"");
    },
    async: false,
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
        var results = data;
        var jsonResult = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(jsonResult.Attributes.length);
    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: That error is telling you the API is not CORS enabled. Use a proxy on a server you control to make the request

Comment: Microsoft says in the official dynamics 365 documents that the Dynamics API is CORS enabled. So any ideia about how can I achieve to make the request?

Comment: Just telling you what missing Access control headers mean. Do a search for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` will find a huge amount of information